# Linking Data in Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am designing a forum and have a layout like this in on my Firebase:

```
root
 |-posts
    |-postID1
        |-creator: "userOne"
        |-creatorUID: "simplelogin:1"
        |-text: "Some Text"
    |-postID2
        |-creator: "userTwo"
        |-creatorUID: "simplelogin:2"
        |-text: "Some Other Text"
 |-profile
    |-simplelogin:1
        |-firstName: "John"
        |-user: "userOne"
    |-simplelogin:2
        |-firstName: "Sue"
        |-user: "userTwo"
```

On my forum page. I simply use a Angular `ng-repeat` to get all of the posts on Firebase and list them out. I also want to print out the first name of whoever created the post, but right now, I can only access `{{ post.creator }}`, which just gives the username of the person who posted. How can I link the post's creator (or creatorUID) with the first name field of that person's profile?

Comment: If you're using AngularFire, see https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/extending-services.html#section-firebasearray. If you're not using AngularFire, see https://github.com/firebase/firebase-util/blob/master/src/NormalizedCollection/README.md.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just displaying the the users firstName I would place the users name in the postIDX object.

This would be quicker and produce less requests to Firebase with you going back and fourth with each post to get the usersFirst name.

more information on structuring data and best practices can be found here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html

**Updated from response**

if you wanted to get the user details then within every request to the postIDx you'd need to do something similar to this (not tested and quick mock up).

```
var fbRef = new Firebase('firebase path'),
    postDetailsObject = {};

fbRef.child('posts').once('value', function(snapshot) {
    // loop through each post
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
          var postDetails = childSnapshot.val(),
              profileDetails;

              postDetailsObject.post = postDetails;

              fbRef.child('profile/' + postDetails.creatorUID).once('value', function(profileData) { 
                  postDetailsObject.profile = profileData; 
              }); 
    })
});
```

Then return the postDetailsObject in to angular so you can loop through the single object.

Comment: I could do this, however I don't this this method scales. What if I have multiple user attributes? I wouldn't want to store all of them with each post/comment.